# Setting a specific area bgcolor for python's 'turtle import'

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I have searched the web for info but all I can find is what I already know:

```
    from turtle import *
    bgcolour('gold')
```

now what I want is to have something that will make half the screen one colour and half another split by specific corner coodinates.
e.g.

```
    from turtle import *
    bgcolour('gold')
    (-200, -150 to -200, 150)
```

so that it will set only in a specific area.

Comment: You can't. But you can draw a filled rectangle to act as a second background color.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to implement it yourself, e.g. like this:

```
from turtle import *

def left_bgcolor(c):
    showturtle()
    penup()
    w = window_width()
    h = window_height()
    penwidth = 10
    # set a big pen width so the turtle is visible while drawing
    width(penwidth)
    # adjust position so we're inside the window border
    goto(-w/2 + penwidth/2, -h/2+penwidth)
    setheading(90)  # north

    pendown()
    color(c, c)     # set both drawing and fill color to be the same color
    begin_fill()
    forward(h - penwidth)
    right(90)
    forward(w/2 - penwidth)
    right(90)
    forward(h - penwidth)   # could be optimized..
    right(90)
    forward(w/2 - penwidth)
    right(90)
    end_fill()

    penup()
    goto(0,0)  # end by setting the turtle in the middle of the screen 
    width(1)
    color('black', 'white')
    setheading(90)

screen = Screen()
left_bgcolor('orange')
```

Comment: The issue I see with this implementation is that it uses the default turtle and doesn't completely restore it's state.  It nicely restores the color, position and pen width but the orientation is different and the pen is left up instead of down.  Following this immediately with `circle(100)` draws nothing as the pen is up.  Instead of restoring state, using your own hidden turtle instance would have been simpler and not changed the default turtle's state.  I will try such with my own solution.

Answer (score 0):

This is yet another situation where *stamping* is simpler than *drawing*.  I've also used a separate turtle instance so the default turtle is left as-is for the user:

```
import turtle

STAMP_UNIT = 20

def left_bgcolor(color):
    squirtle = turtle.Turtle(shape="square", visible=False)
    squirtle.penup()
    screen = turtle.Screen()
    width = screen.window_width() / 2
    height = screen.window_height()
    squirtle.setx(-width / 2)
    squirtle.shapesize(height / STAMP_UNIT, width / STAMP_UNIT)
    squirtle.color(color)
    squirtle.stamp()

left_bgcolor('gold')

turtle.circle(100)

turtle.exitonclick()
```